# iterating array on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How could I go about writing a snippet, that could iterate through array on refresh? 
Say I have an array with banner links, and I'd like the banner to change to next one when refreshed. There is a lot of solutions to make it random, but I want it to loop through array in order, and go to the first one after last.

```
var banner = new Array();
 banner[0] = "http://placehold.it/728x90?text=one";
 banner[1] = "http://placehold.it/728x90?text=two";
 banner[2] = "http://placehold.it/728x90?text=three";
 banner[3] = "http://placehold.it/728x90?text=four";

 for(var i=0; i < banner.length; i++){
  var img = document.getElementById("imageid");
  img.src = banner[i];
 }
```

This is the code that I currently have, but it's obviously not working.

Thank you in advance

Comment: set a [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) value and update based on that

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: banner[i], seems to always be set to 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) like so:

```
var banner = new Array();
banner[0] = "http://placehold.it/728x90?text=one";
banner[1] = "http://placehold.it/728x90?text=two";
banner[2] = "http://placehold.it/728x90?text=three";
banner[3] = "http://placehold.it/728x90?text=four";    

if (!localStorage.i || localStorage.i == 3) localStorage.i = 0;
else localStorage.i++;

var img = document.getElementById("imageid");
img.src = banner[localStorage.i];
```

Explanation: At first page load, `localStorage.i` will be `0`. When you refresh, the value increases by `1` only until `3`, then back to `0` afterwards.

Comment: `localStorage` holds values as `String` so it never will be `=== 3`

Comment: Thank you, this is working, I was not very familiar with localStorage property.

Comment: you should also check for `localStorage`, it is not available everywhere